# Files appear as changed after I run lint on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code, lint

After I execute npm run lint, VScode shows me in source control that a lot of files on my project are modified, when I click on source control to see the actual modified files, no changes appear at all in the actual they are highlighted only in source control as modified. In my team all of my colleagues are using MAC(they don't have this problem) and I'm the only one who uses Windows. I don't have any clue why this issue occurs.

Comment: It could be because of changed permissions or line endings. Use a diff tool to find the differences. There have to be differences otherwise Git wouldn't show that the files have been modified. `gitk` or `git gui` present such differences.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the answer to it based on some guidance on the comments because I had no idea how to solve this problem(I'm a junior with 2weeks experience :D).

So, basically the problem that I was encountering was created by cross-platforming formats of code CR/LF and LF and it's whitespace interpretation that generated changes on my windows machined after I run the npm format.
The solution I found it's on Formatting and Whitespace:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

I've made two changes on git config:

$ git config --global core.autocrlf true

$ git config --global core.whitespace 
trailing-space,-space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab,tab-in-indent,cr-at-eol

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Kappa Ro is right, the problem is related to the  end of line settings.
To solve this, I added endOfLine in my prettier file.

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "printWidth": 140,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

Now the situation you described doesn't happen anymore.